# Specifying URL address. Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I have Web app, which is deployed by instructions: open **localhost:port/manager** open .war file and click deploy. That's ok. Site is working through **localhost:port/appname**. So I want this address to connect from outside not only local PC. I need to specify URL for my site. How?

Comment: Instead of localhost use the IP address of the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use it within local network then you can use your local IP address instead of localhost.

```
localip:port/appname
```

You can find the IP of your machine running ipconfig/ifconfig command on the command prompt.

If you want to open it over the internet then you need a public IP for this and associated configurations.This will be quite some task.

Comment: I have public IP and I know it). I need these associated configurations which are specific for Apache Tomcat.

Comment: @dimiks there is nothing required to be done on tomcat.

Comment: It seems that I need to specify Host at server.xml. I tried to do it but nothing works anyway.

Comment: i dont think anything is required...your ip:port combinantion should be working over the internet....check ur port, whether it is open for outside connections....firewall config

Comment: Don't you know which rule has to be changed or added, please.